# Qual o último script executado na inicialização do Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS e em qual arquivo ele é chamado?

Tags: ubuntu

Nas versões anteriores a versão ubuntu server 12.04, o `rc.local` era o último arquivo da inicialização a ser executado, porém nas versões superiores e especificamente 14.04 LTS Server, o `rc.local` é executado na metade do processo da inicialização, estou precisando muito alterar esta ordem e inserir o `rc.local` como o último script de inicialização a ser executado. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

A documentção oficial do ubuntu diz o seguinte:

> What order are initscripts started and stopped in?
>
> If a service has not been converted to upstart, this has not changed; the symlinks are named SNNname or KNNname, where NN is a number from 00 to 99. The K scripts are run first in numerical order, followed by the S scripts in numerical order.
>
> However, services which have been converted to upstart will define their start criteria in the file, like this:
>
> start on runlevel [2345] stop on runlevel [!2345]
>
> This means the service will be started when the system reaches runlevel 2, 3, 4, or 5. It should be noted that it will be started in parallel with every other service that starts on those runlevels, and anything else still starting. The [!2345] in the stop on means it will be stopped whenever a runlevel that is *not* 2, 3, 4, or 5 is reached.

Então eu concluo que há um upstart service que deve estar chamando o teu `/etc/init.d/rc.local` paralelamente a outros init scripts.

Sugiro que seja criado um init script à moda antiga (`sysvinit`) em `/etc/rcX.d/S99script` , onde X é o teu default runlevel (confira o teu em `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` . Isso deve garantir que ele será executado por último.

Comment: Vou tentar e retorno. Obrigado!